# 6 Player X-Men Arcade Cabinet Compatibility

Tags: hardware, arcade, gaming

I've got a 6-player X-Men Arcade cabinet and I was wondering what other boards might be compatible with it. Can I use any Jamma compatible board? Will the dual monitors just mirror?

Here's a [link to the manual](http://arcarc.xmission.com/PDF_Arcade_Manuals_and_Schematics/X-Men_(6%20player).pdf) with wiring info.

[Originally [asked](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/295093/6-player-x-men-arcade-cabinet-compatibility) in Arqade, with no response]

Comment: Please give a bit more information about the hardware, such as the shapes and pins of the connectors, and perhaps a photograph of the bits of board that plug into things. This will make it easier to identify the cabinet you are referring to, and provide information about ports that would otherwise need to be looked up.

Comment: I'll try to snag some pics. Until then I've updated the question with the manual which has all the technical illustrations. I want to say it's a standard Jamma harness, but I'm not sure if there's extra wires because of the two monitors and extra controls.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The board seems to be using standard Jamma connector for Player 1 and Player 2 except for the `-5V` and the `test switch`. Player 3-6 controls are using non-standart sub-harnesses.

Practically any 6 player game which doesn't require -5V should work. But you may need to modify those sub-harnesses. I didn't see the details of the arcade monitor in the link you provided. You should check refresh rate of the monitor, too.